# Creating Structured array by Recursive function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, recursion

I have a table

[image]

Which I want show recursively like below picture

[image]

I am using a recursive function in php

```
function  reccall($cat_id)
 {
   global $no,$recArray;
   $sql = "SELECT a.*
      FROM cat_master   
           WHERE 
        parent_id = $cat_id 
      ORDER BY 
        id ASC
      ";
         $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not fetech Recursively");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
      $recArray[$no]['value'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row->value);
      $recArray[$no]['id'] = $row->id;
       ++$no;
      reccall($row->id);
    }
    return $recArray;    
 }
```

but I am not able to generate a structured array like how the order is not the picture. A simple array is created all the time. Can anyone help me with creating the structured array like the order shown above.

Comment: You might like [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) by Mike Hillyer

Comment: You should be using [Closure Tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) instead .. or at least: read [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book.

Comment: Also .. stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Yes I like but I need to fetch value recursively so that example is not given here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function instead of your function and your problem will be solved I hope

```
function reccall($cat_id)
 {
     $sql = "SELECT a.*
      FROM cat_master   
           WHERE 
        parent_id = $cat_id 
      ORDER BY 
        id ASC
      ";
         $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not fetech Recursively");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
      $recArray[$no]['main']['value'] = mysql_real_escape_string($row->value);
      $recArray[$no]['main']['id'] = $row->id;         
      $recArray[$no]['child'] = reccall($row->id);
       ++$no;
    }
    return $recArray;    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
// I identified this function separately because it is performed only once, for preparing data
// It's collect an array of all parents in the correct order for each id
function dest($array) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if($value['pid']==0) continue;

        $pid = $key;
        $array[$key]['dest'] = array();
        while ( $pid = $array[$pid]['pid'] ) {
            if($key == $pid) exit("this tree is broken");
            $array[$key]['dest'][] = $pid;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
// Recursive function that puts the items in the correct tree. removes the parameter dest.
function tree($array) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if( is_array($value['dest']) && !empty($value['dest']) ) {
            $pid = array_pop($value['dest']);
            if( empty($value['dest']) ) unset($value['dest']);

            $array[$pid]['childrens'][$key] = $value;
            $array[$pid]['childrens'] = tree($array[$pid]['childrens']);
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

$array = array(
    1 => array(
        'title'=>'q',
        'pid'=>0,
        ),
    2 => array(
        'title'=>'w',
        'pid'=>1,
        ),
    3 => array(
        'title'=>'e',
        'pid'=>0,
        ),
    4 => array(
        'title'=>'r',
        'pid'=>2,
        ),
    5 => array(
        'title'=>'t',
        'pid'=>1,
        ),
);

$tree = tree( dest($array) );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print_r($tree);
?>
```

By the way, I should note that these arrays are not very useful. Better to use the result of the function `dest()`.